# Using annotation for method call

Tags: java, annotations

Can I use annotations on method call? `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)` and  `@Target(ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE)` do not seem to work, IntelliJ throws "*Annotations are not allowed here*".
Is there a way to use annotations like this:

```
 class Test{ 
    void testA(){}  //Method declaration here

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
    @MyAnnotation 
    testA(); //annotation used at method invocation
  } 
}
```

Am I able to do this without using any framework like Spring? Only with JavaSE or JavaEE.